# Can’t get proper output based upon input and conditions?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I can’t get this code to output correctly.  As you can see I’m asking a user to input a name that appears in a tuple and if that name is in said tuple they will be granted access.  Otherwise, if the name isn’t in the variable they will be denied.

```
authorized_users = ("Sheldon", "Mark", "Daniel")
user_input = input("Please enter your name: ")

if user_input is in authorized_users:
 print("Access Granted!")
 print(f"Hello {user_input}!")
else:
 print("Access Denied!")
```

I just get a syntax error on line 4.  I have tried changing is and in to just == to get the result I want, however, that doesn’t work.

```
authorized_users = ("Sheldon", "Mark", "Daniel")
user_input = input("Please enter your name: ")

if user_input is in authorized_users:
 print("Access Granted!")
 print(f"Hello {user_input}!")
else:
 print("Access Denied!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid of the `is`. The `in` is a perfectly suitable operator by itself in this situation.

```
authorized_users = ("Sheldon", "Mark", "Daniel")
user_input = input("Please enter your name: ")

if user_input in authorized_users:
 print("Access Granted!")
 print(f"Hello {user_input}!")
else:
 print("Access Denied!")
```

You may wish to store the `authorized_users` tuple as all lowercase names, and then lowercase the input to make the check case-insensitive.